# How to select inside a FOR-Loop for further computations?

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, postgis, plpgsql

Working with postgresql and postgis I have 2 openstreetmap tables, containing:

1. Point: Locations with a single coordinate
2. Polygon: Areas with sets of coordinates

Now, I'm trying to loop through the Point table and for each record I'm trying to do some computations with postgis functions, e.g. `ST_Intersects()`. Then trying to insert the results into another tables.

So far I've only done simple `SELECT` queries with postgis functions, they basically work like this:

```
SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM   table_point AS a, table_polygon AS b
WHERE  a.name = 'Berlin' AND ST_Intersects(a.way, b.way);
```

Note: `way` is the column in both tables containing geometry data.

Coming back to the loop I want to operate, I find myself with lacking plpgsql basics. I've created the following loop structure, but don't know how to select a second set of records (`table_point AS a, table_polygon AS b`) for the postgis function.
Short: How to select the records for `table_polygon` along with that FOR-loop?
Or, is there a better way to solve this?

```
DO
$do$

DECLARE
r RECORD;

BEGIN
FOR r IN SELECT * FROM table_point
LOOP
RAISE NOTICE '%', r;

...

END LOOP;
END;
$do$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Using PGSQL 9.3.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking procedurally, while for most cases a set-based approach is superior in relational databases. Like:

```
INSERT INTO table_other (point, polygon, result)
SELECT a.name, b.name, calculate(a.?, b.?) AS result -- undefined what to do
FROM   table_point   a
JOIN   table_polygon b ON ST_Intersects(a.way, b.way)
WHERE  a.name = 'Berlin';
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define r2 as a record..

then do something like:

```
FOR r IN SELECT * FROM table_point
LOOP
RAISE NOTICE '%', r;
   for r2 in select * from table2 where table2.id=r.somecolumn
   LOOP
   --perform calcs here
   end loop;

END LOOP;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, much Love to you!

Comment: I answered your question directly, however, Erwin's answer is a better solution to the overall problem you're trying to solve. My solution just solved your syntax issues, not your method of querying.